# Help Center's search feature should search "Privileges" section as well

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

I realized that the Help Center's search doesn't return results from its ["Privileges" section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). For example, the [list of results from searching "community wiki"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=community+wiki) doesn't include the ["Edit Community Wiki" privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

I'm not sure if this is an oversight or if this is by design. The "Privileges" section does have a non-FAQ structure, so this might or might not explain why it is excluded from the search feature.

I find the "Privileges" pages to be very informational when trying to learn about various site features, such as [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), and [down-voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). On top of that, the "Privileges" section *is* a part of the Help Center, so it's counter-intuitive that you can't search that part of the Help Center.

Comment: Hmmm... searching for "Privileges" does not find any hits in the "Reputation & Privileges" or "Privileges" sections!

Comment: It's called "Reputation & Moderation" now, but the search looks for stuff in that section (try searching "voting"). "Privileges" isn't being searched though. Neither is "Badges" (but I don't care much for searching for badges)

Comment: I was searching in Meta's help.

Comment: We're looking into this now.  I'm not changing the status yet, as I don't have the detail on what's involved, but we agree that this makes sense.

Comment: @Jaydles And since privileges section is being included into the help-center searches; it'd make sense to include [the Badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) section as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Privileges pages have all been ported over to the Help Center and as of today are indexed in the help center search. We did not include the badges section because those pages are very easily accessible to anyone looking for information about badges - they have a top-level nav placement between the "users" and "unanswered" buttons on every site.

A side effect of this change is that privilege pages are no longer wikis editable by users here on MSO; in order to index them with the help center pages, we needed to relocate those pages to a place with different permissions. The community team is now in charge of making any updates that may be required going forward, so if you see any out-of-date or missing information from a privileges page, post to meta requesting it to be updated.