# Variables not expanded in search, in Help Center

Tags: bug, search, help-center

I was searching in [Stack Overflow's Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) with [the search term *privileges*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=privileges), trying to find [the Privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), but I can't (that [was reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189650/204869)). However, it seems that it actually found pages containing `$Privilege` instead, i.e. with a dollar sign.

> [image: Help Center search result, word "privilege" prefixed with dollar sign]

Looks like it's searching for raw pages whose variables were not replaced by their values yet. For example, in the search result, it shows this sentence:

> If you have at least **$Privilege-CloseQuestion** reputation points, vote to reopen yourself.

However, in [the actual page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), the sentence is:

> If you have at least **3,000** reputation points, vote to reopen yourself.

Comment: Nice work with freehand circles. :)

Comment: It's a known issue.

Comment: Related/duplicate (much newer, but also much higher score): [Required rep values for privileges appears as '$Privilege-<PrivilegeName>' in help center search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371128/335251)