# Required rep values for privileges appears as '$Privilege-<PrivilegeName>' in help center search results

Tags: bug, search, help-center

The parameter for reputation points values required for privileges is not resolved in the help center search results.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=privilege%20tag%20wiki):

[image: Stack Overflow Search results that has the text for users with $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits]

[Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=privilege%20tag%20wiki):

[image: Sci-Fi and Fantasy Search results that has the text for users with $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits]

This should probably be resolved here, or not reveal the variable name used at least.

Comment: Related/duplicate (much older, but your post has a much higher score): [Variables not expanded in search, in Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197756/335251)